# Run a Java application with JDK 13 on NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, java-13

I work with Netbeans 11.1 and with JDK 8, but I want to try some feature of JDK 13 and I encountered difficulties.

After installing JDK 13, I added the platform in Netbeans in Tools -> Java Platforms, and in the project's properties I indicated that the Java platform is JDK 13.

I wrote the following Java 13 code, but Netbeans does not recognize it as valid:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String html = """
<html>
    <body>
        <p class="text">Hello, Text Blocks</p>
    </body>
</html>""";
}
```

I thank you for telling me what steps I should take to configure the environment to run this code

Comment: It looks like it is/will be supported since NetBeans 11.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Minor updates made to the instructions following the formal release of Apache NetBeans 11.2.]*

To use the text blocks feature in JDK 13 with NetBeans:

- <del>Install a beta version of NetBeans 11.2. You can download the zip file for a recent build of 11.2 (at your own risk) from https://builds.apache.org/view/M-R/view/NetBeans/job/netbeans-TLP/job/netbeans/job/release112/30/artifact/dist/</del>
- [Download Apache NetBeans 11.2](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb112/nb112.html). (Earlier releases will not work.)
- <del>On that page click the link for **netbeans-11.2-vc1-bin.zip** to download it. Unzip the downloaded file to any directory,</del> Install NetBeans 11.2 from the downloaded file, and then start NetBeans 11.2 from **.../bin/netbeans.exe**
- Create a trivial Java project using **File > New Project... > Java with Ant > Java Application**, then edit its `main()` method by copying/pasting the code from the `main()` method in the OP.
- Build the project. In the **Output** window you will see the error message *"text blocks are a preview feature and are disabled by default ... (use --enable-preview to enable text blocks)"*:
  [image]
- Now position the mouse cursor over the red circle next to the declaration of `String html...` and click the mouse. You should see a tooltip, and also a message stating "*Enable Preview Feature*":
  [image: enablePreview]
- Hit {enter}. The project will be modified to support text blocks, and the compilation error should be gone.
- Add a call to `System.out.println(html);` at the end of the `main()` method, then run the project. You should see the value of `html` displayed in the **Output** window:
  [image]

**Notes:**

- Enabling the preview feature appears to make the following changes to your project's properties:

  - **Build > Compiling > Additional Compiler Options** is set to  `--enable-preview`
  - **Run > VM Options** is also set to `--enable-preview`
- You must use NetBeans 11.2 for this to work, even though you can use JDK 13 with NetBeans 11.1 with no obvious issues.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/Apache+NetBeans+11.2), NetBeans 11.2 will support Java 13.

The official release of 11.2 should be real soon now.  According to the current [release schedule](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/Release+Schedule) page it should happen by October 31st.  Apparently, the [vote](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/a562f51f614364f931a35f8dfd310cfd15ebf44b150e40277e94ff40@%3Cdev.netbeans.apache.org%3E) on the [final release candidate](https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/netbeans/netbeans/11.2-vc1/) has [passed](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/09b8d9f0174721de6d7969e7cb10ad946152a20757c1be15c3098046@%3Cdev.netbeans.apache.org%3E).

But if you are extra impatient, you don't need an fancy IDE to experiment with Java 13.  A text editor and command line tools will work.

Comment: All true, but it's worth noting that when using **javac** and **java** from the command line you must also specify ***--enable-preview*** because support for text blocks is not enabled by default; in JDK 13 the text block is a [preview language feature](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/12).